# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy is not overriding existing allow all egress policy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

There is already two existing Network Policies present and one of which allows all the outbound traffic for all pods

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-default
  namespace: sample-namespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-egress
  namespace: sample-namespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector: {}
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
```

and I want to block all outbound traffic for a certain pod with label `app: localstack-server` so I created one more Network Policy for it but its not getting applied on that Pod

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: psp-localstack-default-deny-egress
  namespace: sample-namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: localstack-server
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

I'm able to run `curl www.example.com` inside that pod and its working fine which it should not have.

Comment: Pod must be run in sample-namespace and your k8s network driver must support network policies. Check if deny all policies work for you.

Answer (score 1):

NetworkPolicies are additive, and they only have allow rules. So for each pod (as selected by podSelector), the traffic that will be allowed is the sum of all network policies that selected this pod. In your case, that's all traffic, since you have a policy that allows all traffic for an empty selector (all pods).

To solve your problem, you should apply the allow all policy to a label selector that applies to all pods, except that one app: localstack-server. So,  add a label like `netpol-all-allowed: true`, and don't add it to `localstack-server.`NetworkPolicies are additive, and they only have allow rules. So for each pod (as selected by podSelector), the traffic that will be allowed is the sum of all network policies that selected this pod. In your case, that's all traffic, since you have a policy that allows all traffic for an empty selector (all pods).

To solve your problem, you should apply the allow all policy to a label selector that applies to all pods, except that one app: localstack-server. So,  add a label like `netpol-all-allowed: true`, and don't add it to `localstack-server.`

Comment: Thanks @orisho for the reply. Is there a way to apply NetworkPolicy to all Pods except pods with certain label?

Answer (score 0):

I think yor first yaml you allowed all egress, because in the [Kubernetes Network Policy documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) following network policy is given with the explanation:

> With this policy in place, no additional policy or policies can cause any outgoing connection from those pods to be denied. This policy has no effect on isolation for ingress to any pod.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

Earlier in the docs it says, that

> By default, a pod is non-isolated for egress; all outbound connections are allowed.

So i would suggest to leave out the allow-default rule for egress, then the denying of egress for that pod should work.